# insert values of several cookies into hidden form field

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I have a simple form and need to get the values of cookie(s) inserted into a hiddle field (coupon) within the form.

I have this for the form:

```
<form action="/members/signup" class="am-signup-form" id="page-0" method="post" name="page-0">
<input id="_qf_page-0_next-0" name="_qf_page-0_next" type="submit" value="Get Access Now">
<input type="hidden" name="coupon" id="coupon-0" value="" />
</form>
```

And I have this for the javascript inserted below the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var cookies;

    function readCookie(name,c,C,i){
        if(cookies){ return cookies[name]; }

        c = document.cookie.split('; ');
        cookies = {};

        for(i=c.length-1; i>=0; i--){
           C = c[i].split('=');
           cookies[C[0]] = C[1];
        }

        return cookies[name];
    }

    window.readCookie = readCookie; 
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Get cookie you want.
    var referrer = window.readCookie('readCookie_mycookiename1') || ''; 
    //Set cookie value to hidden field.        
    $('#coupon').val(referrer);
});
</script>
```

I can't seem to get the form/script working properly. The cookie value is not being inserted into the value of the hidden field.

Also, I have 3 differnt cookies that I need to insert into the value of the hidden field. No cookie may be present, 1 cookie may be present, or all 3 cookies may be present (depending on the site visitor).

If all three cookies are present, I need to get them all insterted into the value of the single hidden field (how they look isn't important). Is there a way to modify script so that I can get values from multiple cookies all inserted into the single hidden field value?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of `#coupon` which does not exist. Your hidden input's id is `coupon-0`.

As for getting 0-3 cookies and placing them in the hidden field:

```
function getCookies(...names) {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((cookieObj, cookie) => {
    const [name, value] = cookie.split('=');

    return {
      ...cookieObj,
      [name]: value,
    };
  }, {});

  return names.reduce((values, name) => {
    if (cookies[name]) {
      values.push(cookies[name]);
    }

    return values;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getCookies('_ga', 'cookie_that_doesnt_exist', '_gid'));
```

That will return an array of cookie values, the order will be determined by the order of the names you passed. If the cookie name doesn't exist, it is skipped. Just join the array to set the input value.

Comment: Thank you. With your code, in a php page, I kept getting errors in my editor. I checked an online javascript validator, and it's saying ...cookieObj (around line 6) is an unexpected token. Also, how do I get the script to place the cookie values into the hidden form field?

Comment: You're probably getting an error because it's es6. That function returns an array of strings; just `join` the array and set the `val()` of `$('#coupon-0')`.

Comment: I'm an amateur with javascript. Not sure how to join array and set value to coupon-0. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: `getCookies('yourCookie').join('')`? Like I said, `#coupon` doesn't exist but `#coupon-0` does.

Comment: I understand about the coupon-0, but I'm not understanding what the form field and script should be to make this work. Guess I need to pay a coder who understands javascript better than I do.